# Java jar -Dlog4j2.configurationFile does not generate log file when running via command line

Tags: java, spring-boot, cmd, log4j2, executable-jar

I have an issue in getting to export the log file of log4j2 if I am running it via the command line.

I have an executable jar file that does not contain any other `.properties` files, other than `application.properties` (this file is empty). In my case, I am running my command line as follows:

`java -Dlog4j2.configurationFile=//file:/C:/myApp/CONF/log4j2.properties -jar myApp-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar`

However, in my terminal, no errors are shown, and during the execution, no log file is generated.
Instead, the log file only seems to be exported and generated only if I commented out `SpringApplication.run(App.class, args);` in my main application.

Even so, I believe I need this line to run the spring framework/ architecture side of things (I'm new to spring stuff).
I have tried placing the same `log4j2.properties` within the jar file and it does works (ie. generated the log file however this is not what I intended for)

A sample of my program is as follows:

**Main File - App.java**

```
import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;
import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.context.ConfigurableApplicationContext;


@SpringBootApplication (exclude (DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class })
public class App implements CommandLineRunner {
    private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(App.class);
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // File is generated if only the following line is commented out
        // SpringApplication.run(App.class, args);

        logger.debug("This is debug");
        logger.info("This is info"); 
        logger.error("This is error");
    }
        
    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception { 
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
}
```

**Pom.xml - To enable the export of log4j2 log file**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId> <version>2.17.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId> <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId> <version>2.17.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId> <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-batch</artifactId>
    <exclusions>
        <!-- Excluding logback dependencies to use 14j2 -->
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

**log4j2.properties**

```
status = error
property.filename = C:\\mytest-logs\\debug.log

filters = threshold
filter.threshold.type = ThresholdFilter filter.threshold.level=debug
appenders = rolling
appender.rolling.type = RollingFile 
appender.rolling.name = RollingFile
appender.rolling.fileName = ${filename}
appender.rolling.filePattern = C:\\logs\\Previous\\debug-backup-%d{MM-dd-yy-HH-mm-ss}-xi.log.gz 
appender.rolling.layout.type = PatternLayout
appender.rolling.layout.pattern = %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c(1):%L - %m%n 
appender.rolling.policies.type = Policies
appender.rolling.policies.time.type = TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy 
appender.rolling.policies.time.interval = 1
appender.rolling.policies.time.modulate = true
appender.rolling.policies.size.type = SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy 
appender.rolling.policies.size.size=10MB
appender.rolling.strategy.type = DefaultRolloverStrategy 
appender.rolling.strategy.max = 20

loggers = rolling
logger.rolling.name = mytesting.test_log4js
logger.rolling.level = debug
logger.rolling.additivity = true
logger.rolling.appenderRef.rolling.ref= RollingFile
```

I am using Java version 1.8 and spring boot version 2.2.13.

Appreciate in advance for any insights.

Comment: Try ```java -Dlog4j2.configurationFile=file:/C:/myApp/CONF/log4j2.properties -jar myApp-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar```

Comment: @g00se Tried it, and it is not working :/  Are my file contents correct or am I missing something somewhere?

Comment: I don't use this kind of logging but *property.filename = C:\\mytest-logs\\debug.log* doesn't look quite right: https://springframework.guru/log4j-2-configuration-using-properties-file/ Theirs looks like a *directory* which is then referenced using *${filename}* - all very confusing and I strongly suspect an xml config is preferable